# load list for Split View Controller from another file

Tags: ios, swift

this code works great.
but I want the **Category** to load from (for example) file 1 
and **name** to load from (for example) File 2

```
// MARK: - Properties
var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var candies = [Candy]()
var filteredCandies = [Candy]()
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

// MARK: - View Setup
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

 // Setup the Search Controller
 searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
 searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
 definesPresentationContext = true
 searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

 // Setup the Scope Bar
 searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Chocolate", "Hard", "Other"]
 tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

 candies = [
  Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"Chocolate Bar"),
  Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"Chocolate Chip"),
  Candy(category:"Qukullad", name:"keks")]

 if let splitViewController = splitViewController {
  let controllers = splitViewController.viewControllers
  detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
 }
}
```

Comment: in your case, file1 and file2 are which kind of files ?, your viewController1, viewController2 or plist files ?

Comment: I have a master view controller and a detailed view of the controller code above are from Master View Controller

Comment: I want to convert it into such a code but I do not know how


category = ["file 1"]
name = ["file2"]

Comment: so instead of hard coding values for three candies, you want fetch values from some file ? right ?

Comment: like chocolate and qukullad will be stored some where in file, you want to do this ?

Comment: yes but I do not know how please help me

Comment: there are extremely large amount of data and in a file do not fit in.
therefore drawn up I want to invite from different files